# Schedule each Apache Spark Stage to run on a specific Worker Node

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, distributed-system

Suppose, I am running a simple Wordcount application on Spark (actually Spark Streaming) with 2 worker nodes. By default each task (from any stage) is scheduled to any available resource based on a scheduling algorithm. However, I want to change the default scheduling to fix each stage to a specific worker node.

Here is what I am trying to achieve -

1. Worker Node 'A' should only process the first Stage (like 'map' stage). So all the data that comes in must first go to worker 'A'
2. and Worker Node 'B' should only process the second stage (like 'reduce' stage). Effectively, the results of Worker A are processed by Worker B.

My first question is - Is this sort of customisation possible on Spark or Spark Streaming by tuning the parameters or choosing a correct config option? (I don't think it is, but can someone confirm this?)

My second question is - Can I achieve this by making some change to the Spark scheduler code? I am ok hardcoding the IPs of the workers if necessary. Any hints or pointers to this specific problem or even understanding the Spark Scheduler code in more detail would be helpful..

I understand that this change defeats the efficiency goals of Spark to some extent but I am only looking to experiment with different setups for a project.

Thanks!

Comment: This actually contradicts the principle of data locality that spark is very strict about. I cannot see a way where data that is located in node a will be processed by node b. Unless it is shuffled over there by some operation. Having said that, you could make spark shuffle the day to specific partitions by adding a key to your data and then repartition it by key

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but as @z-star says, you're going to be battling against the spark API the whole time. It's not just task scheduling, but also shuffle service, fault handling would need thought. If this is a money project you might do better looking at Storm/Heron or other tools that expose a more graph-like processing model at a lower level than Sparks set-like paradigm. If it's for a learning/personal project, hit up the Spark mailing lists, clone the code and have at it :)